# Notice: Undefined index ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, pdo

So I have a working zurb-foundation modal and I also have an ajax code that refreshes the div every x number of seconds. Here is the code

index.php

```
<a class="th [radius]" href="view-comments.php?ilid=<?= $img['img_id']; ?>" data-reveal-id="viewCommentModal" data-reveal-ajax="true">View</a>
```

view-comments.php

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
            setInterval(function() {
                $('#load-comments').load('load-comments.php');
            }, 3000)
        });
    </script>
<body>
    <div id="load-comments"></div>
</body>
<a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</html>
```

load-comments.php

```
<?php
    require 'dbc.php';
    $stmt = $dbc->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_comments WHERE img_id=:imageid ORDER by c_id DESC");
    $stmt->bindValue(':imageid', $_GET['ilid']);
    $stmt->execute();
    foreach ($stmt as $data) {
        extract($data);
        echo "<b>{$c_message}</b>";
    }
?>
```

My problem is that every time the load-comments.php is being loaded, it shows the error `Undefined index: ilid in D:\wamp\www\instalike\load-comments.php on line 4`. How can I resolve this? Thanks!

Comment: are short tags enabled? if not, try changing `<?=` to `<?php echo`

Comment: Yes it is enabled. I know the problem is that the loaded data doesn't know where to get value of ilid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass parameter with `load()`, you missed to pass `ilid` here

if you want pass it as `GET` you can do like this

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
       var ilid=25; //change ilid as per your need or move it to setInterval
       setInterval(function() {
             $('#load-comments').load('load-comments.php?ilid=ilid');  
         }, 3000)
       });
```

//load-comments.php

```
<?php
    require 'dbc.php';

    if(isset($_GET['ilid'])){
     $stmt = $dbc->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_comments WHERE img_id=:imageid ORDER by c_id DESC");
     $stmt->bindValue(':imageid', $_GET['ilid']);
     $stmt->execute();
     foreach ($stmt as $data) {
        extract($data);
        echo "<b>{$c_message}</b>";
     }else{
       echo 'Missing ilid';
      }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Hey there can I have a follow-up question?
So in my setInterval(function() {
             $('#load-comments').load('load-comments.php?ilid=ilid');  
         }, 3000) code, How can I add a message like "Loading messages..." before the messages get loaded? Thanks

Comment: @FewFlyBy, in that case `$.ajax` will be the best choice over `$.load()` because with that the `beforeSend`, `error`, `dataFilter`, `success` and `complete` options all accept callback functions that are invoked at the appropriate times. this will help you set your messages easily see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/